# Bind DNS Problems

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-14.04, dns-zone

I have setup a Bind DNS server for my website winpack.cf but it seems that something goes wrong: mxtoolbox shows "Lookup failed after 2 name servers timed out or responded non-authoritatively"...

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and the most weird in my configuration which I think might be kind of a problem (although I believe it shouldn't) is that **the IP of nameservers and main website is the same**. (meaning I have Apache and Bind configured on **THE SAME** computer)

I have configured appropriate glue records, **I am sure**.

My zone configuration file on BIND is:

```
;
; BIND data file for winpack.cf
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA winpack.cf. winpackjason.outlook.com. (
             2015020201     ; Serial
               7200     ; Refresh
               7200     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             900 )      ; Negative Cache TTL
        IN      A       2.84.10.240
;
@   IN  NS  ns.winpack.cf.
ns  IN  A   2.84.10.240
@   IN  A   2.84.10.240
@   IN  MX  10  winpack.cf.
@   IN  TXT "v=spf1 mx a -all"
www IN  CNAME   winpack.cf.
```

Output of "dig +trace +additional winpack.cf":

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> +trace +additional winpack.cf
;; global options: +cmd
.           507723  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           507723  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           517962  IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20150212170000 20150202160000 16665 . SXORQYP2YP2riKiIF0pe0pokD5MIv8cFrT2plo/SXnRFapBFq7nQmpaf 1wMOO984I/N2Y7eu2J+mix98u0wRhLOWCj2/5ST45426escF9TPdzgtx yooBoF7yerydPKV/ou/oNvJBegIpOiYFpNamHtOV3/96ChZXWjTWRz/X PJU=
a.root-servers.net. 587253  IN  A   198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net. 604362  IN  AAAA    2001:503:ba3e::2:30
b.root-servers.net. 95501   IN  A   192.228.79.201
b.root-servers.net. 555723  IN  AAAA    2001:500:84::b
c.root-servers.net. 368668  IN  A   192.33.4.12
c.root-servers.net. 604363  IN  AAAA    2001:500:2::c
d.root-servers.net. 80383   IN  A   199.7.91.13
d.root-servers.net. 604363  IN  AAAA    2001:500:2d::d
e.root-servers.net. 80385   IN  A   192.203.230.10
f.root-servers.net. 80387   IN  A   192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net. 604362  IN  AAAA    2001:500:2f::f
g.root-servers.net. 80384   IN  A   192.112.36.4
h.root-servers.net. 80389   IN  A   128.63.2.53
h.root-servers.net. 604362  IN  AAAA    2001:500:1::803f:235
i.root-servers.net. 135814  IN  A   192.36.148.17
i.root-servers.net. 604362  IN  AAAA    2001:7fe::53
j.root-servers.net. 76216   IN  A   192.58.128.30
j.root-servers.net. 604363  IN  AAAA    2001:503:c27::2:30
k.root-servers.net. 76216   IN  A   193.0.14.129
k.root-servers.net. 604362  IN  AAAA    2001:7fd::1
l.root-servers.net. 76216   IN  A   199.7.83.42
l.root-servers.net. 604363  IN  AAAA    2001:500:3::42
m.root-servers.net. 1655    IN  A   202.12.27.33
m.root-servers.net. 70832   IN  AAAA    2001:dc3::35
;; Received 913 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 56 ms

cf.         172800  IN  NS  a.ns.cf.
cf.         172800  IN  NS  b.ns.cf.
cf.         172800  IN  NS  c.ns.cf.
cf.         172800  IN  NS  d.ns.cf.
cf.         86400   IN  NSEC    cg. NS RRSIG NSEC
cf.         86400   IN  RRSIG   NSEC 8 1 86400 20150212170000 20150202160000 16665 . u1+7qdhGOIXsZ/xweAE8o1y1/H0JHCeGj+U74Hxzmft8z7fSOmdB2YO8 czo2g4al/sjmit+ViNnChzZ8nDRXSuFfXfytINyO79WqDz7yb/Q77Fxr XLVXiWOhgI3bnb/zfXlosmKh1zPhKMFa496vGzbaqPuSwj5ML2zMIw93 mTE=
a.ns.cf.        172800  IN  A   185.21.168.17
b.ns.cf.        172800  IN  A   185.21.169.17
c.ns.cf.        172800  IN  A   185.21.170.17
d.ns.cf.        172800  IN  A   185.21.171.17
a.ns.cf.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:4::1
b.ns.cf.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:5::1
c.ns.cf.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:6::1
d.ns.cf.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:7::1
;; Received 465 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 62 ms

winpack.cf.     300 IN  NS  ns.winpack.cf.
winpack.cf.     300 IN  NS  ns2.winpack.cf.
ns.winpack.cf.      7200    IN  A   2.84.10.240
ns2.winpack.cf.     7200    IN  A   2.84.10.239
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns.winpack.cf': no more
```

(Do **NOT** take into account nameserver ns2: it is **not** working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2.84.10.240` does not respond to dns queries (wrong ip, host down or blocked by firewall)

```
$ dig @2.84.10.240 www.winpack.cf

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @2.84.10.240 www.winpack.cf
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If the host is up and the ip address is correct, make sure you allow incoming traffic on port 53 on both udp and tcp protocols

Comment: Thank you very much!! You saved me! I didn't expect it to be **SO** simple! THANK YOU.....